# Como um construtor const se diferencia de um construtor padrão?

Tags: construtor, dart

Na documentação diz que o construtor `const` *Cria um objeto que nunca mudará. Todas 'vars' tem que ser final*.

Então significa que terei o mesmo resultado na criação das seguintes classes?

```
class Produto {
  const Produto({this.nome});
  final String nome;
}

class Produto2 {
  Produto2({this.nome});
  final String nome;
}
```

Como o conceito de construtor const realmente funciona? Como um construtor const pode ser usado de forma vantajosa em relação a um construtor normal?

*Baseada na pergunta:* [How does the const constructor actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744677/how-does-the-const-constructor-actually-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lendo as respostas *linkadas* parece que nem eles entenderam muito bem para que serve :) Mas a conclusão é que, grosso modo, ela funciona como uma tupla nominada. Ela serve para você criar uma espécie de literal de um tipo, então você pode usar o construtor como se fosse esse literal onde cria o objeto normalmente, mas essa sintaxe permite que o compilador interprete o dado como um literal e pode analisar melhor em tempo de compilação, ou seja ele entende como o objeto se comportará em tempo de execução já em tempo de compilação e pode fazer algumas operações que dependem disto ou fazer otimizações.

Lá mostra que o construtor na verdade não é um [construtor como conhecemos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), ele não tem implementação e não faz nada específico, até porque provavelmente ele faz algo padrão, por isso o compilador já sabe o que fazer, e para garantir que o literal mantém estado do objeto o tempo todo todos os campos do objeto devem ser finais, ou seja, constantes, e claro, todos os campos precisam ser inicializados de uma forma ou de outra.

Eles usam o termo *canonicalizar* o objeto porque se eles possuem os mesmos dados eles são considerados o mesmo objeto. Objetos canônicos conhecidos em tempo de compilação podem ser usados em lugares onde só aceita literais, como enumerações, valores de `switch`, anotações, além de já citado melhorar a performance, incluindo aí uma comparação ser feita de forma direta sem envolver processamento em tempo de execução.

Internamente ele deve tratar o objeto como uma coisa única, assim como um número inteiro é uma coisa única e pode ser comparado de forma direta, é uma forma de mostrar que o objeto é algo estático e simples, sem regras especiais.

Answer (score 1):

Sem entrar em pormenores e teorias mirabolantes que poucos irão ler, você está direcionando a pergunta a Dart, e eu irei direcioná-la especificamente ao Flutter (que é o principal uso de Dart hoje em dia).

Ao acessarmos o SDK, iremos presenciar vários usos de construtores const entre os Widgets, principalmente os `StatelessWidget`s, de fato, se criarmos um `StatelessWidget` com atributos `final` e pedirmos para a IDE criar um construtor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela irá criar automaticamente um construtor `const`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E parafraseando a [documentação de Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#consider-making-your-constructor-const-if-the-class-supports-it):

> **CONSIDER making your constructor const if the class supports it.**
>
> If you have a class where all the fields are final, and the constructor does nothing but initialize them, you can make that constructor const. That lets users create instances of your class in places where constants are required—inside other larger constants, switch cases, default parameter values, etc.

Além de ser uma boa prática, Flutter se beneficia muito disso para sua performance. Isso porque um StatelessWidget construído através de um construtor `const` pode ser reaproveitado na árvore de Widgets, pois esse objeto criado é canonicalizado, o que significa que, independente de quantas vezes esse valor constante for chamado no código, sempre vai existir apenas um único objeto na memória. Por exemplo esse código onde criamos 2 objetos List com `const` em Dart, [veja aqui na prática](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/65e557b2d0b044796268180bfa4dc540):

```dart
main() {
  var a = const [1,2,3];
  var b = const [1,2,3];
  print('A e B são os mesmos objetos? ${identical(a, b)}');
}
```

O que em Flutter acontece bastante nos casos de adição de padding com o famoso `const EdgeInsets.all(8.0)`. Imagine adicionar o mesmo valor de 'padding' em vários lugares da árvore de Widgets.

Outra questão é que, uma vez que esse objeto é imutável, seus valores são `final` e ele foi construído com um construtor `const`, ao reconstruir a árvore de Widgets, esses Widgets `const` que obviamente não foram alterados, não precisam ser reconstruídos, ocorrendo uma otimização na utilização do `setState()`.

Comment: Ótima resposta, favor repita essa resposta nessa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/403700/como-o-uso-de-construtores-cons-pode-melhor-a-performance-no-flutter @julio-henrique-bitencourt