# Como o uso de construtores 'const' pode melhorar a performance no Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Na [documentação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html) uma das recomendações para melhorar a performance das aplicações em Flutter diz:

*Use widgets constantes sempre que possível e forneça um construtor const...*

Como se dá a melhora/otimização da performance com esse tipo de prática?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De fato ao navegarmos pelo código fonte do SDK do Flutter vamos presenciar vários Widgets Stateless com um construtor `const`. Isso porque em teoria todos os `StatelessWidget`s são imutáveis e devem conter seus atributos definidos como `final`, consequentemente podendo fazer uso de um construtor `const`.

Utilizar um construtor `const` significa que todo o estado do objeto pode ser definido em tempo de compilação, por isso é necessário que os atributos sejam `final`.

Inclusive ao criarmos um `StatelessWidget` com atributos final e pedirmos para a IDE(AndroidStudio no exemplo) criar um construtor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ela irá criar automaticamente um construtor const:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso porque o plugin de Dart da IDE segue ao máximo as boas práticas [definidas na linguagem](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#consider-making-your-constructor-const-if-the-class-supports-it):

> **CONSIDER making your constructor const if the class supports it.**
>
> If you have a class where all the fields are final, and the constructor does nothing but initialize them, you can make that constructor const. That lets users create instances of your class in places where constants are required—inside other larger constants, switch cases, default parameter values, etc.

Além de ser uma boa prática, Flutter se beneficia muito disso para sua performance.

Sabemos que todos os Widgets são renderizados em uma árvore, e ao atualizarmos essa árvore de estados (utilizando `setState()`), todos os Widgets filhos também são renderizados novamente, o `build()` é reexecutado. Por exemplo esse código:

```dart
return Container(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      const Text('eu não mudei..')
    ],
  ),
);
```

Ao executarmos o `setState` o `build` do `Container` será executado, após isso o de seus filhos, nesse caso a `Row`. Porém, como o SDK tem a certeza de que o Text não sofreu alterações, ele não precisa ser recriado. É importante salientar que Flutter é inteligente o suficiente para identificar se um Node/Widget da árvore foi ou não modificado para sua renderização, mas o const auxilia nesse processo, além de permitir também a canonicalização deste objeto, imagine este outro exemplo:

```dart
return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: const Text('canonicalizado'),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Note que o uso do `EdgeInsets` em toda a nossa árvore de Widgets é muito comum para atribuição de padding. Acima, quando utilizamos const na primeira criação deste objeto, o mesmo foi canonicalizado ou 'congelado', ou seja, todos os demais locais que utilizaram o mesmo objeto (como o `Padding`) irão apontar para a mesma referência do objeto em memória, sem a necessidade de criar várias instâncias de um mesmo objeto.