# Fluxo de notificação de alteração

Tags: flutter, dart

Eu já entendi como funciona o processo de mudança de estado de um `widget` no qual o mesmo é 'atualizado' para mostrar seu novo valor. Porém, a documentação fala do fluxo ou seja, o caminho que é percorrido:

*In Flutter, change notifications flow “up” the widget hierarchy by way of callbacks, while current state flows “down” to the stateless widgets that do presentation. The common parent that redirects this flow is the State. The following slightly more complex example shows how this works in practice:*

Eu gostaria de entender como exatamente funciona esse fluxo 'pra cima' quando se refere a notificar mudança, enquanto que o estado atual flui 'para baixo' para o `widget` que faz a apresentação.

*Exemplo referente a frase em inglês:

```
class CounterDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  CounterDisplay({this.count});

  final int count;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('Count: $count');
  }
}

class CounterIncrementor extends StatelessWidget {
  CounterIncrementor({this.onPressed});

  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: Text('Increment'),
    );
  }
}

class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterState createState() => _CounterState();
}

class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _increment() {
    setState(() {
      ++_counter;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: <Widget>[
      CounterIncrementor(onPressed: _increment),
      CounterDisplay(count: _counter),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, como visualmente é sempre melhor o entendimento, vamos ver como ficaria de forma simplificada essa árvore de Widgets do código que você passou de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que o `Counter` é o Widget que está mantendo o estado da variável `_counter`, assim como é o responsável pela implementação do método `_increment()` que atualiza o `_counter`.

Um outro ponto é que a referência para esse método `_increment` é passada para os Widgets filhos dessa árvore, até o `RaisedButton`, onde será utilizada como a implementação do seu `onPressed`.

Quando o botão é clicado então, o seu `onPressed` é executado, só que a implementação está lá no nosso Widget pai, então isso ocorre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O processo de 'flow up' mencionado acontece, esse processo também é chamado de **callback**, pois o Widget lá abaixo da árvore **'chama novamente'** um Widget acima da hierarquia.

Quando essa função `_increment` é então executada, ela atualiza o valor do `_counter` e executa o `setState`, como bem sabemos, esse é um método especial em Flutter que avisa o SDK de que ele precisa atualizar o estado dos Widgets, acontecendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao atualizar o `setState` ocorre o processo de 'flows down', afinal, todos os Widgets abaixo nessa hierarquia terão o seu `build` reexecutado para se adequarem ao novo estado, então `Text` que mostra o `_counter` lá abaixo da árvore irá mostrar o novo valor.

> Na prática o Flutter é inteligente o suficiente para saber se o estado
>   do Widget foi alterado para sua reexecução, isso envolve utilização de
>   Widgets const como [explicado aqui por exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/403700/como-o-uso-de-construtores-const-pode-melhorar-a-performance-no-flutter/403761#403761).

Vale lembrar que:

- Toda essa questão de gerenciamento de estado em Flutter sempre rende uma boa e longa discussão, no geral não é muito recomendado gerenciar estado apenas com o uso do `setState`, por conta dessa questão de atualização de toda a árvore.
- Vale a pena sempre conhecer o gerenciamento de estados com [Bloc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options#bloc--rx) ou [Provider](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options#provider--scoped-model), os mais aceitos no momento.

Comment: Eu já imaginava que era isso que ocorria mas sem a explicação da imagem estava difícil de assimilar. Como estou iniciando quero conhecer o básico pra depois me aprofundar com Bloc, Provider, etc.

Obrigado pela ótima explicação.