# Como utilizar o linter no flutter/dart para melhorar a qualidade do código?

Tags: flutter, dart, linting

No flutter/Dart o Lint (processo que analisar o código para identificar possíveis erros.) vem por padrão com algumas regras 'flexíveis' que permite um código com erros compilar e executar.

Tais regras pode deixar passar erros graves, tais como:

```
FloatingActionButton(
  child: Icon(Icons.announcement),
);
```

`warning The parameter 'onPressed' is required`

A falta do parâmetro `onPressed` causa apenas um `warning` quando na verdade não deveria sequer compilar.

Outro caso que é bastante comum é a omissão do `const` que pode resultar em perda de desempenho, [mais detalhes aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/403700/como-o-uso-de-construtores-const-pode-melhorar-a-performance-no-flutter).

```
Text(
    'You have pushed the button this many times:',
),
```

Como configurar o Lint para garantir uma maior qualidade no código?

Comment: Não sei se já encontrou algo específico para os casos que citou, mas até onde sei existem algumas regras pré-definidas que podem ser customizadas. Também não cheguei a utilizar mas vou deixar aqui algumas referências que encontrei que talvez possam ser úteis a você: -https://medium.com/podiihq/setting-up-lint-rules-in-dart-flutter-1ebbed0418a6 (um tuto rápido) / https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/ (lints do dart) / https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options (referência na doc do dart)

Comment: @LeonardoPaim Obrigado, vou ler a documentação

Answer (score 0):

Exitem alguns pacotes com regras mais rígidas que garantem uma melhor qualidade e padronização do código, segue alguns deles:

- [pedantic](https://pub.dev/packages/pedantic)
- [effective dart](https://pub.dev/packages/effective_dart)
- [lint](https://pub.dev/packages/lint)

Como qualquer outro pacote é necessário adicioná-lo ao projeto através do `pubspec.yaml`, utilizando com exemplo o pacote `lint` a configuração ficaria:

```
dev_dependencies:
  lint:
```

> `dev_dependencies` - Por se tratar de um pacote utilizando somente no
>   ambiente de desenvolvimento

Para utilizar as novas regras crie o (`analysis_options.yaml`) na pasta raiz do projeto e adicionar as definições das regras:

```
include: package:lint/analysis_options.yaml
```

Para personalizar veja a documentação em [Customizing static analysis](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#the-analysis-options-file)